# convert synchronous websocket callbacks to async in python using asyncio

Tags: python, websocket, python-3.6, python-asyncio

need you assistance to convert asynchronous websocket callbacks to async using asyncio in python 3.6.
Some brokers in India provide a websocket for tick data to their users and users can further use this tick data, one such brokers sample code(from their git repo) is pasted here

```
`from smartapi import SmartWebSocket

# feed_token=092017047
FEED_TOKEN="YOUR_FEED_TOKEN"
CLIENT_CODE="YOUR_CLIENT_CODE"
# token="mcx_fo|224395"
token="EXCHANGE|TOKEN_SYMBOL"    #SAMPLE: nse_cm|2885&nse_cm|1594&nse_cm|11536&nse_cm|3045
# token="mcx_fo|226745&mcx_fo|220822&mcx_fo|227182&mcx_fo|221599"
task="mw"   # mw|sfi|dp

ss = SmartWebSocket(FEED_TOKEN, CLIENT_CODE)

def on_message(ws, message):
    print("Ticks: {}".format(message))
    
def on_open(ws):
    print("on open")
    ss.subscribe(task,token)
    
def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)
    
def on_close(ws):
    print("Close")

# Assign the callbacks.
ss._on_open = on_open
ss._on_message = on_message
ss._on_error = on_error
ss._on_close = on_close

ss.connect()
```

so what I think the broker is doing is that it provides messages/ticks aka events that probably trigger a callback function on every received messages/tick in a synchronous way.
I however want to alter the above code so that it can work in an async manner, I have tried to write in a manner how binance provides such as `async with websocketName('currencyPair')as ts:` but this doesn't seem to work with my broker.
Appreciate if you can share some ideas/code/insights around this.
Thank you for your time.

Edit 1:
Thank you for your response Dirn,

Yes, I've tried this

```
from smartapi import SmartConnect 
from smartapi import SmartWebSocket 
import logging
import asyncio


CLIENT_CODE = Code_provided_by_broker
PASSWORD = My_Password

obj=SmartConnect(api_key=My_api_key)
data = obj.generateSession(CLIENT_CODE, PASSWORD)
refreshToken = data['data']['refreshToken']
print("refreshToken", refreshToken)

feedToken=obj.getfeedToken()
print("feedToken", feedToken)

FEED_TOKEN= feedToken

token="nse_cm|3499"
# token="nse_fo|53595"
task = 'mw'


async def on_message(ws, message):
    print("Ticks: {}".format(message))


async def chk_msg():

    # ss = SmartWebSocket(FEED_TOKEN, CLIENT_CODE)
    # ss.subscribe(task,token)
    # ss._on_message =  on_message
    # ss.connect()    
    # print("Ticks: {}".format(message))


    async with SmartWebSocket(FEED_TOKEN, CLIENT_CODE) as ss: #throws an error: AttributeError: __aexit__
        ss.subscribe(task,token)
        ss.connect()
        while True:
            ss._on_message = on_message # not sure how to await a non-async method _on_message, also there is no use of async module in the modules(imported at start of the script) SmartWebSocket and SmartConnect
            

if __name__ == "__main__":

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(chk_msg())
```

here is the smartConnect.py

```
from six.moves.urllib.parse import urljoin
import sys
import csv
import json
import dateutil.parser
import hashlib
import logging
import datetime
import smartapi.smartExceptions as ex
import requests
from requests import get
import re, uuid
import socket
import platform
from smartapi.version import __version__, __title__

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
#user_sys=platform.system()
#print("the system",user_sys)

class SmartConnect(object):
    #_rootUrl = "https://openapisuat.angelbroking.com"
    _rootUrl="https://apiconnect.angelbroking.com" #prod endpoint
    #_login_url ="https://smartapi.angelbroking.com/login"
    _login_url="https://smartapi.angelbroking.com/publisher-login" #prod endpoint
    _default_timeout = 7  # In seconds

    _routes = {
        "api.login":"/rest/auth/angelbroking/user/v1/loginByPassword",
        "api.logout":"/rest/secure/angelbroking/user/v1/logout",
        "api.token": "/rest/auth/angelbroking/jwt/v1/generateTokens",
        "api.refresh": "/rest/auth/angelbroking/jwt/v1/generateTokens",
        "api.user.profile": "/rest/secure/angelbroking/user/v1/getProfile",

        "api.order.place": "/rest/secure/angelbroking/order/v1/placeOrder",
        "api.order.modify": "/rest/secure/angelbroking/order/v1/modifyOrder",
        "api.order.cancel": "/rest/secure/angelbroking/order/v1/cancelOrder",
        "api.order.book":"/rest/secure/angelbroking/order/v1/getOrderBook",
        
        "api.ltp.data": "/rest/secure/angelbroking/order/v1/getLtpData",
        "api.trade.book": "/rest/secure/angelbroking/order/v1/getTradeBook",
        "api.rms.limit": "/rest/secure/angelbroking/user/v1/getRMS",
        "api.holding": "/rest/secure/angelbroking/portfolio/v1/getHolding",
        "api.position": "/rest/secure/angelbroking/order/v1/getPosition",
        "api.convert.position": "/rest/secure/angelbroking/order/v1/convertPosition",

        "api.gtt.create":"/gtt-service/rest/secure/angelbroking/gtt/v1/createRule",
        "api.gtt.modify":"/gtt-service/rest/secure/angelbroking/gtt/v1/modifyRule",
        "api.gtt.cancel":"/gtt-service/rest/secure/angelbroking/gtt/v1/cancelRule",
        "api.gtt.details":"/rest/secure/angelbroking/gtt/v1/ruleDetails",
        "api.gtt.list":"/rest/secure/angelbroking/gtt/v1/ruleList",

        "api.candle.data":"/rest/secure/angelbroking/historical/v1/getCandleData"
    }


    try:
        clientPublicIp= " " + get('https://api.ipify.org').text
        if " " in clientPublicIp:
            clientPublicIp=clientPublicIp.replace(" ","")
        hostname = socket.gethostname()
        clientLocalIp=socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception while retriving IP Address,using local host IP address",e)
    finally:
        clientPublicIp="106.193.147.98"
        clientLocalIp="127.0.0.1"
    clientMacAddress=':'.join(re.findall('..', '%012x' % uuid.getnode()))
    accept = "application/json"
    userType = "USER"
    sourceID = "WEB"
    

    def __init__(self, api_key=None, access_token=None, refresh_token=None,feed_token=None, userId=None, root=None, debug=False, timeout=None, proxies=None, pool=None, disable_ssl=False,accept=None,userType=None,sourceID=None,Authorization=None,clientPublicIP=None,clientMacAddress=None,clientLocalIP=None,privateKey=None):
        self.debug = debug
        self.api_key = api_key
        self.session_expiry_hook = None
        self.disable_ssl = disable_ssl
        self.access_token = access_token
        self.refresh_token = refresh_token
        self.feed_token = feed_token
        self.userId = userId
        self.proxies = proxies if proxies else {}
        self.root = root or self._rootUrl
        self.timeout = timeout or self._default_timeout
        self.Authorization= None
        self.clientLocalIP=self.clientLocalIp
        self.clientPublicIP=self.clientPublicIp
        self.clientMacAddress=self.clientMacAddress
        self.privateKey=api_key
        self.accept=self.accept
        self.userType=self.userType
        self.sourceID=self.sourceID

        if pool:
            self.reqsession = requests.Session()
            reqadapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(**pool)
            self.reqsession.mount("https://", reqadapter)
            print("in pool")
        else:
            self.reqsession = requests

        # disable requests SSL warning
        requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
    def requestHeaders(self):
        return{
            "Content-type":self.accept,
            "X-ClientLocalIP": self.clientLocalIp,
            "X-ClientPublicIP": self.clientPublicIp,
            "X-MACAddress": self.clientMacAddress,
            "Accept": self.accept,
            "X-PrivateKey": self.privateKey,
            "X-UserType": self.userType,
            "X-SourceID": self.sourceID
        }

    def setSessionExpiryHook(self, method):
        if not callable(method):
            raise TypeError("Invalid input type. Only functions are accepted.")
        self.session_expiry_hook = method
    
    def getUserId():
        return userId

    def setUserId(self,id):
        self.userId=id

    def setAccessToken(self, access_token):

        self.access_token = access_token

    def setRefreshToken(self, refresh_token):

        self.refresh_token = refresh_token

    def setFeedToken(self,feedToken):
        
        self.feed_token=feedToken

    def getfeedToken(self):
        return self.feed_token

    
    def login_url(self):
        """Get the remote login url to which a user should be redirected to initiate the login flow."""
        return "%s?api_key=%s" % (self._login_url, self.api_key)
    
    def _request(self, route, method, parameters=None):
        """Make an HTTP request."""
        params = parameters.copy() if parameters else {}
       
        uri =self._routes[route].format(**params)
        url = urljoin(self.root, uri)


        # Custom headers
        headers = self.requestHeaders()

        if self.access_token:
            # set authorization header
        
            auth_header = self.access_token
            headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer {}".format(auth_header)

        if self.debug:
            log.debug("Request: {method} {url} {params} {headers}".format(method=method, url=url, params=params, headers=headers))
    
        try:
            r = requests.request(method,
                                        url,
                                        data=json.dumps(params) if method in ["POST", "PUT"] else None,
                                        params=json.dumps(params) if method in ["GET", "DELETE"] else None,
                                        headers=headers,
                                        verify=not self.disable_ssl,
                                        allow_redirects=True,
                                        timeout=self.timeout,
                                        proxies=self.proxies)
           
        except Exception as e:
            raise e

        if self.debug:
            log.debug("Response: {code} {content}".format(code=r.status_code, content=r.content))

        # Validate the content type.
        if "json" in headers["Content-type"]:
            try:
                data = json.loads(r.content.decode("utf8"))
             
            except ValueError:
                raise ex.DataException("Couldn't parse the JSON response received from the server: {content}".format(
                    content=r.content))

            # api error
            if data.get("error_type"):
                # Call session hook if its registered and TokenException is raised
                if self.session_expiry_hook and r.status_code == 403 and data["error_type"] == "TokenException":
                    self.session_expiry_hook()

                # native errors
                exp = getattr(ex, data["error_type"], ex.GeneralException)
                raise exp(data["message"], code=r.status_code)

            return data
        elif "csv" in headers["Content-type"]:
            return r.content
        else:
            raise ex.DataException("Unknown Content-type ({content_type}) with response: ({content})".format(
                content_type=headers["Content-type"],
                content=r.content))
        
    def _deleteRequest(self, route, params=None):
        """Alias for sending a DELETE request."""
        return self._request(route, "DELETE", params)
    def _putRequest(self, route, params=None):
        """Alias for sending a PUT request."""
        return self._request(route, "PUT", params)
    def _postRequest(self, route, params=None):
        """Alias for sending a POST request."""
        return self._request(route, "POST", params)
    def _getRequest(self, route, params=None):
        """Alias for sending a GET request."""
        return self._request(route, "GET", params)

    def generateSession(self,clientCode,password):
        
        params={"clientcode":clientCode,"password":password}
        loginResultObject=self._postRequest("api.login",params)
        
        if loginResultObject['status']==True:
            jwtToken=loginResultObject['data']['jwtToken']
            self.setAccessToken(jwtToken)
            refreshToken=loginResultObject['data']['refreshToken']
            feedToken=loginResultObject['data']['feedToken']
            self.setRefreshToken(refreshToken)
            self.setFeedToken(feedToken)
            user=self.getProfile(refreshToken)
        
            id=user['data']['clientcode']
            #id='D88311'
            self.setUserId(id)
            user['data']['jwtToken']="Bearer "+jwtToken
            user['data']['refreshToken']=refreshToken

            
            return user
        else:
            return loginResultObject
    def terminateSession(self,clientCode):
        logoutResponseObject=self._postRequest("api.logout",{"clientcode":clientCode})
        return logoutResponseObject

    def generateToken(self,refresh_token):
        response=self._postRequest('api.token',{"refreshToken":refresh_token})
        jwtToken=response['data']['jwtToken']
        feedToken=response['data']['feedToken']
        self.setFeedToken(feedToken)
        self.setAccessToken(jwtToken)

        return response

    def renewAccessToken(self):
        response =self._postRequest('api.refresh', {
            "jwtToken": self.access_token,
            "refreshToken": self.refresh_token,
            
        })
       
        tokenSet={}

        if "jwtToken" in response:
            tokenSet['jwtToken']=response['data']['jwtToken']
        tokenSet['clientcode']=self. userId   
        tokenSet['refreshToken']=response['data']["refreshToken"]
       
        return tokenSet

    def getProfile(self,refreshToken):
        user=self._getRequest("api.user.profile",{"refreshToken":refreshToken})
        return user
    
    def placeOrder(self,orderparams):

        params=orderparams
       
        for k in list(params.keys()):
            if params[k] is None :
                del(params[k])
        
        orderResponse= self._postRequest("api.order.place", params)['data']['orderid']
    
        return orderResponse
    
    def modifyOrder(self,orderparams):
        params = orderparams

        for k in list(params.keys()):
            if params[k] is None:
                del(params[k])

        orderResponse= self._postRequest("api.order.modify", params)
        return orderResponse
    
    def cancelOrder(self, order_id,variety):
        orderResponse= self._postRequest("api.order.cancel", {"variety": variety,"orderid": order_id})
        return orderResponse

    def ltpData(self,exchange,tradingsymbol,symboltoken):
        params={
            "exchange":exchange,
            "tradingsymbol":tradingsymbol,
            "symboltoken":symboltoken
        }
        ltpDataResponse= self._postRequest("api.ltp.data",params)
        return ltpDataResponse
    
    def orderBook(self):
        orderBookResponse=self._getRequest("api.order.book")
        return orderBookResponse
        

    def tradeBook(self):
        tradeBookResponse=self._getRequest("api.trade.book")
        return tradeBookResponse
    
    def rmsLimit(self):
        rmsLimitResponse= self._getRequest("api.rms.limit")
        return rmsLimitResponse
    
    def position(self):
        positionResponse= self._getRequest("api.position")
        return positionResponse

    def holding(self):
        holdingResponse= self._getRequest("api.holding")
        return holdingResponse
    
    def convertPosition(self,positionParams):
        params=positionParams
        for k in list(params.keys()):
            if params[k] is None:
                del(params[k])
        convertPositionResponse= self._postRequest("api.convert.position",params)

        return convertPositionResponse

    def gttCreateRule(self,createRuleParams):
        params=createRuleParams
        for k in list(params.keys()):
            if params[k] is None:
                del(params[k])

        createGttRuleResponse=self._postRequest("api.gtt.create",params)
        #print(createGttRuleResponse)       
        return createGttRuleResponse['data']['id']

    def gttModifyRule(self,modifyRuleParams):
        params=modifyRuleParams
        for k in list(params.keys()):
            if params[k] is None:
                del(params[k])
        modifyGttRuleResponse=self._postRequest("api.gtt.modify",params)
        #print(modifyGttRuleResponse)
        return modifyGttRuleResponse['data']['id']
     
    def gttCancelRule(self,gttCancelParams):
        params=gttCancelParams
        for k in list(params.keys()):
            if params[k] is None:
                del(params[k])
        
        #print(params)
        cancelGttRuleResponse=self._postRequest("api.gtt.cancel",params)
        #print(cancelGttRuleResponse)
        return cancelGttRuleResponse
     
    def gttDetails(self,id):
        params={
            "id":id
            }
        gttDetailsResponse=self._postRequest("api.gtt.details",params)
        return gttDetailsResponse
    
    def gttLists(self,status,page,count):
        if type(status)== list:
            params={
                "status":status,
                "page":page,
                "count":count
            }
            gttListResponse=self._postRequest("api.gtt.list",params)
            #print(gttListResponse)
            return gttListResponse
        else:
            message="The status param is entered as" +str(type(status))+". Please enter status param as a list i.e., status=['CANCELLED']"
            return message

    def getCandleData(self,historicDataParams):
        params=historicDataParams
        for k in list(params.keys()):
            if params[k] is None:
                del(params[k])
        getCandleDataResponse=self._postRequest("api.candle.data",historicDataParams)
        return getCandleDataResponse
        
    def _user_agent(self):
        return (__title__ + "-python/").capitalize() + __version__
```

the smartApiWebsocket.py

```
import websocket
import six
import base64
import zlib
import datetime
import time
import json
import threading
import ssl

class SmartWebSocket(object):
    ROOT_URI='wss://wsfeeds.angelbroking.com/NestHtml5Mobile/socket/stream'
    HB_INTERVAL=30
    HB_THREAD_FLAG=False
    WS_RECONNECT_FLAG=False
    feed_token=None
    client_code=None
    ws=None
    task_dict = {}
    
    def __init__(self, FEED_TOKEN, CLIENT_CODE):
        self.root = self.ROOT_URI
        self.feed_token = FEED_TOKEN
        self.client_code = CLIENT_CODE
        if self.client_code == None or self.feed_token == None:
            return "client_code or feed_token or task is missing"

    def _subscribe_on_open(self):
        request = {"task": "cn", "channel": "NONLM", "token": self.feed_token, "user": self.client_code,
                   "acctid": self.client_code}
        print(request)
        self.ws.send(
            six.b(json.dumps(request))
        )
        
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run, args=())
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            # More statements comes here
            if self.HB_THREAD_FLAG:
                break
            print(datetime.datetime.now().__str__() + ' : Start task in the background')
            
            self.heartBeat()

            time.sleep(self.HB_INTERVAL)
    
    def subscribe(self, task, token):
        # print(self.task_dict)
        self.task_dict.update([(task,token),])
        # print(self.task_dict)
        if task in ("mw", "sfi", "dp"):
            strwatchlistscrips = token  # dynamic call
        
            try:
                request = {"task": task, "channel": strwatchlistscrips, "token": self.feed_token,
                           "user": self.client_code, "acctid": self.client_code}
        
                self.ws.send(
                    six.b(json.dumps(request))
                )
                return True
            except Exception as e:
                self._close(reason="Error while request sending: {}".format(str(e)))
                raise
        else:
            print("The task entered is invalid, Please enter correct task(mw,sfi,dp) ")
    
    def resubscribe(self):
        for task, marketwatch in self.task_dict.items():
            print(task, '->', marketwatch)
            try:
                request = {"task": task, "channel": marketwatch, "token": self.feed_token,
                           "user": self.client_code, "acctid": self.client_code}
        
                self.ws.send(
                    six.b(json.dumps(request))
                )
                return True
            except Exception as e:
                self._close(reason="Error while request sending: {}".format(str(e)))
                raise
        
    def heartBeat(self):        
        try:
            request = {"task": "hb", "channel": "", "token": self.feed_token, "user": self.client_code,
                       "acctid": self.client_code}
            print(request)
            self.ws.send(
                six.b(json.dumps(request))
            )
    
        except:
            print("HeartBeat Sending Failed")
            # time.sleep(60)
           
    def _parse_text_message(self, message):
        """Parse text message."""
     
        data = base64.b64decode(message)
        
        try:
            data = bytes((zlib.decompress(data)).decode("utf-8"), 'utf-8')
            data = json.loads(data.decode('utf8').replace("'", '"'))
            data = json.loads(json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
        except ValueError:
            return
        
        # return data
        if data:
            self._on_message(self.ws,data)
    
    def connect(self):
        # websocket.enableTrace(True)
        self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(self.ROOT_URI, 
                                     on_message=self.__on_message, 
                                     on_close=self.__on_close, 
                                     on_open=self.__on_open,
                                     on_error=self.__on_error)
        
        self.ws.run_forever(sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE})

    def __on_message(self, ws, message):
        self._parse_text_message(message)
        # print(msg)
            
    def __on_open(self, ws):
        print("__on_open################")
        self.HB_THREAD_FLAG = False
        self._subscribe_on_open()
        if self.WS_RECONNECT_FLAG:
            self.WS_RECONNECT_FLAG = False
            self.resubscribe()
        else:
            self._on_open(ws)
    
    def __on_close(self, ws):
        self.HB_THREAD_FLAG = True
        print("__on_close################")
        self._on_close(ws)
              
    def __on_error(self, ws, error):
                             
        if ( "timed" in str(error) ) or ( "Connection is already closed" in str(error) ) or ( "Connection to remote host was lost" in str(error) ):
            
            self.WS_RECONNECT_FLAG = True
            self.HB_THREAD_FLAG = True
           
            if (ws is not None):
                ws.close()
                ws.on_message = None
                ws.on_open = None
                ws.close = None    
                # print (' deleting ws')
                del ws
       
            self.connect()
        else:
            print ('Error info: %s' %(error))
            self._on_error(ws, error)

    def _on_message(self, ws, message):
        pass
            
    def _on_open(self, ws):
        pass
    
    def _on_close(self, ws):
        pass
              
    def _on_error(self, ws, error):
        pass
```

the provider has also imported the websocket module in the above smartApiWebsocket file and has also provided a custom webSocket.py

here is the link webSocket.py
[enter link description here](https://github.com/angelbroking-github/smartapi-python/blob/main/SmartApi/webSocket.py)

Comment: In order to help, we need to see what you’ve tried (code you’re using) and what specific problem(s) you’re having.

Comment: Yes, I've mentioned the things you have suggested Dirn

Comment: Your websocket library doesn’t appear to be asyncio-aware. You’ll need to find or write another one that is if you want to use it with asyncio.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your prompt response, the library not being asyncio-aware was one of the things I suspected, and thank you for the confirmation.